# Get inner nested dictionary with key stored in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested

I have this list:

```
n = ['FAKE0.0.1.8', '10.2.2.22', '10.2.182.10', '10.2.20.5', '10.2.94.135', '10.2.110.1', '10.2.94.73', '10.2.20.1', '10.2.94.38', '10.2.94.37', '10.2.7.121']
```

And this dictionary:

```
i = {'10.2.94.38': {'area': '0.0.1.8'}}
```

As you can see, there is only one item inside the list, which is a valid key for the dictionary: `10.2.94.38`.

If I do the following, I can get the inner diciontary `{'area':'0.0.1.8'}`:

```
>>> [i.get(x,'NA') for x in n]
['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', {'area': '0.0.1.8'}, 'NA', 'NA']
```

If I do the following, I can get the value `0.0.1.8`, as usual:

```
>>> i[n[8]]['area']
'0.0.1.8'
```

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot reach the ultimate value `0.0.1.8`. I've tried the following without success:

```
>>> [i.get(x['area'],'NA') for x in n]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I do it? The final result that I want to achieve is:

```
['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', '0.0.1.8', 'NA', 'NA']
```

Thanks!

Lucas

Comment: `x` is a string here `x['area']`, not a dict

Comment: I don't follow. Could you elaborate a little bit may be?

Comment: `for x in n` where `n` is your list and `x` is a list item(string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `try` / `except`:

```
n = ['FAKE0.0.1.8', '10.2.2.22', '10.2.182.10', '10.2.20.5', '10.2.94.135',
     '10.2.110.1', '10.2.94.73', '10.2.20.1', '10.2.94.38', '10.2.94.37', '10.2.7.121']

i = {'10.2.94.38': {'area': '0.0.1.8'}}

def try_get_all(i, n):
    for j in n:
        try:
            yield i[j]['area']
        except KeyError:
            yield 'NA'

res = list(try_get_all(i, n))

# ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', '0.0.1.8', 'NA', 'NA']
```

Comment: With this I only get the value `0.0.1.8`. The problem is that my final output should be a list of `len(n)` with items `NA` if no match with the dictionary or the value `0.0.18` if there is a match ...

Comment: Hi! Sorry but after the update I only get `>>> try_get(i_set, n_set)
'0.0.1.8'`.... :-( ... I should get something like `['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', '0.0.1.8', 'NA', 'NA']`

Comment: You are right. That's why I've updated it ... sorry for the late update. After the discussion I realized I needed something else ... And your suggestion is working very nice. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LucasAimaretto, no problem, I've simplified the solution further for you :).

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple , don't make it complicated:

```
n = ['FAKE0.0.1.8', '10.2.2.22', '10.2.182.10', '10.2.20.5', '10.2.94.135', '10.2.110.1', '10.2.94.73', '10.2.20.1', '10.2.94.38', '10.2.94.37', '10.2.7.121']
i = {'10.2.94.38': {'area': '0.0.1.8'}}

print([i[x]['area'] if x in i else 'NaN' for x in n])
```

output:

```
['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', '0.0.1.8', 'NaN', 'NaN']
```

If you only want values then you can also filter the result:

```
n = ['FAKE0.0.1.8', '10.2.2.22', '10.2.182.10', '10.2.20.5', '10.2.94.135', '10.2.110.1', '10.2.94.73', '10.2.20.1', '10.2.94.38', '10.2.94.37', '10.2.7.121']
i = {'10.2.94.38': {'area': '0.0.1.8'},'10.2.2.22':{'area': '0.0.1.9'}}


print(list(map(lambda x:i[x]['area'],filter(lambda x:x in i,n))))
```

output:

```
['0.0.1.9', '0.0.1.8']
```